# Table not being created SQLite

Tags: android

Okay so i have an issue with the creation of an additional table, initially I created a table called Contacts which worked fine.

I then integrated an additional table  Messages into my onCreate method within my DBHandler to be created,  this is when i started getting issues.

First of all logcat would just refuse to even give an error as to why it wasn't working, then i removed the program off of my avd to start with a fresh new database folder in case this was the issue and now it issuing a syntax error near the my table messages, i have also changed my DBVersion no.

Here is my DBHandler, i believe the problem is occurring within the onCreate method, with the Create messages table.

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "forensicsproject";
//====================================================
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = "phone_number";
//====================================================
private static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "messages";
private static final String MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON = "person";
private static final String MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY = "body";
private static final String MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
//private static final  MESSAGES_COLUMN_DATE = "date";      //TODO              


public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
            Log.e("CONTACT", "CREATED"); 

    String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PIMRARY KEY," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE);
            Log.e("MESSAGES", "CREATED");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS + TABLE_MESSAGES);      
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME, contact.getName()); 
    values.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONENUMBER, contact.getPhoneNumber()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    Log.e("CONTACTS", "INSERTED");
    db.close(); 
}

public void getMessages(Messages messages) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON, messages.getPerson()); 
    values.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY, messages.getBody()); 
    values.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS, messages.getAddress());
    values.put(MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE, messages.getType());
    db.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, values);
    Log.e("MESSAGES", "INSERTED");
    db.close(); 

   }

  }
```

Comment: show your logcat please

Comment: Hi Please check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: `String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PIMRARY KEY," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";` I guess you meant **PRIMARY**.

Comment: wow yeah, how did i not spot that. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your code:

```
 String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_MESSAGES + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PIMRARY KEY," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT," 
            + MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

As someone already pointed out, you need to make it the **`PRIMARY`**`KEY` but you also need to add a space to the `"CREATE TABLE" +` in order to make it a proper SQL statement `"CREATE TABLE " +` once the table name is concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

from @Rotwang

`String CREATE_MESSAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_MESSAGES + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PIMRARY KEY," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_PERSON + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + MESSAGES_COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";`

I guess you meant **PRIMARY**